# Finding $f(2019)$ in definite integration

Tags: integration

If $\displaystyle f(n)=\int^{1}_{0}(1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1})(1+3x+5x^2+\cdots +(2n-1)x^{n-1})dx$. Then $f(2019)$ is

What I tried:

$$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$

and $$1+3x+5x^2+\cdots +(2n-1)x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{2(1-x^n)}{1-x}-\frac{(2n-1)x^n}{1-x}$$

How do I solve it? Help me, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By making change of variable $x=t^2$, we obtain
$$\begin{align*}
f(n)&=2\int_0^1 t(1+t^2+\cdots +t^{2n-2})(1+3t^2+5t^4+\cdots +(2n-1)t^{2n-2})dt.
\end{align*}$$ Further making substitution $u=t+t^3+\cdots +t^{2n-1}$, we get
$$
f(n)=2\int_0^n u\ du=\left[u^2\right]^n_0=n^2.
$$ So $f(2019)=2019^2$ follows.

Comment: +1 for this excellent answer, and also for the many other excellent answers you have posted.

Comment: @TobyMak Your kind words make me feel rewarded for participating in the MSE community. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: This is such an elegant answer! You are a genius! +1

Comment: @clathratus Thank you very much for your praise :-) But there are many people on the MSE who are marvelous at integrals, and most of the time I'm just learning from them, including you!